# Find the coefficients of the polynomial...

Tags: polynomials

We have the polynomial $P(x)=x^4-3x^2-4$ and $Q(x)=x^2+mx+n$. Find the real coefficients of $m$ and $n$ , so that $P(x)$ is divisible to $Q(x)$.

Excuse for no signs of my work, the problem is I really do not how. Frankly, I've tried to divide the polynomials, but I think that's a stupid idea and the remainder should be zero, but this didn't work. So thank you in advance for your possible help!

Comment: Can you factorize them?

Comment: Factorize the first polynomial?

Comment: In what sense did dividing not work? "The remainder should be zero" sounds like an equation you can solve.

Comment: well, both. Clearly, if polynomials divide each other, they share roots.

Comment: Note that $Q(x)$ will divide $P(x)$ if the roots of $Q(x)$ are also roots of $P(x)$ (and multiple roots are multiple roots). $Q$ being quadratic has two roots. In the general case where the roots of $P$ are distinct (as here, in fact) there will be six different ways of picking an unordered pair of roots from $P$ to be the roots of $Q$. Whether these methods give you answers depends on the constraints on the coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $P(x)$ is divisible by $Q(x)$, then $Q(x)$ and $P(x)$ should have common roots.

Comment: Oooo, thank you very much now I understand

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$x^4 - 3x^2 - 4 = (\color{blue}{\bf x^2})^{\bf 2} - 3(\color{blue}{\bf x^2}) - 4 = (x^2 - 4)(x^2 + 1)= (x-2)(x+2)(x^2 + 1)$$

Comment: Also note $x^2-4=(x+2)(x-2)$

Comment: I appreciate your help, thank you!!!

Comment: Yes, Alizter, indeed.

Comment: You're welcome, John!

Comment: @JohnG. Note that $(x^2+1)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb R$ so that means that the quadratic $Q$ must be comprised of the other factors. And just because I can in $\Bbb C$, $(x^2+1)=(x+i)(x-i)$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Using Middle Term factor,

$$z^2-3z-4=z^2-(4-1)z-4$$

Again,
$$z^2-4z+z-4=(z-4)(z+1)$$

Set $z=x^2$

Comment: YOur advise helped me a lot, thanks!

Comment: @JohnG., nice to hear that

Answer (score 0):

So how I understood we have $P(x)=(x^2-4)(x^2+1)$
So if $P(x)$ is divisible to $Q(x)$ so they share the same solutions, so:

$Q(-2)=4-2m+n=0$  and $Q(2)=4+2m+n=0$
So we find $m$ and $n$!!!

Is it right?

Comment: There are two solutions

Comment: Yes, 2 and -2  !

Comment: I think @MarkBennet meant two pairs of solutions

Comment: May be I am wrong but x^2+1 has no solutions so we have one pair of solutions

Comment: $x^2+1 \implies x=i,-i$

Comment: But the coefficients should be real?!

Comment: I couldn't understand your last comment, however, what I understood you meant is that for $x=i,-i$ does not count for real $m,n$. But, $m,n$ are sum of products of roots respectively,which are real.

Comment: I meant that the coefficients should not be complex numbers --from condition of the exercise

Comment: Co-efficients are real when you consider the imaginary solution. As,$m=i+(-i)=0,n=i.(-i)=1$

Comment: I understand, thank you

Comment: Easiest to see that $x^2+1$ is in the required form so must provide a solution.

Comment: @MarkBennet Very true.